# aws-sdk (v 2.395.0) and react-native

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

Am in the throes of upgrading a react native application that I've inherited responsibilities for, and am coming across some build issues after upgrading react native.

I have decided to nuke the old project (based on RN 0.53.3) and created a new project with RN 0.58.2. After shoe horning the source in, my builds to simulator were getting hung up in the metro bundler at ~99%, with the application eventually timing out telling me that it Could not connect to development server.

Unable to effectively debug the issue, I have been going file by file, code dependency by dependency to narrow down the issue, and the first issue that is causing this hang up is actually the **aws-sdk** npm module.

After simply adding the `import AWS from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native'` statement, build demonstrates the outlined behavior.

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Could not connect to development server.

Ensure the following:
- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
- WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server

URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.))

__38-[RCTCxxBridge loadSource:onProgress:]_block_invoke.226
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:412
___ZL36attemptAsynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURLP5NSURLU13block_pointerFvP18RCTLoadingProgressEU13block_pointerFvP7NSErrorP9RCTSourceE_block_invoke.118
-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]
__88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
-[NSBlockOperation main]
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
__NSOQSchedule_f
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_continuation_pop
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread2
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

RN Environment information is as follows:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
      Memory: 1.04 GB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 7, 8, 9
        Build Tools: 19.1.0, 21.1.2, 22.0.1, 23.0.1, 23.0.2, 25.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.2
        System Images: android-22 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
      react-native: 0.58.3 => 0.58.3 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
      react-native-patch: 0.2.0
```

Comment: you can try this [max-old-space-size react-native](https://medium.com/@ttqluong93/react-native-max-old-space-size-2af6754b5926)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the attachment.. After struggling of 2 days we got a solution by Max-old-size in xcode.

[image: Please find attachment]